# Retrieving data from Azure Mobile Services

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I am making a Windows 10 app with an Azure backend which I started to integrate and when I try to retrieve data I am getting the most odd error, please see code below:

Code in App.xaml.cs

```
// Setting up a client to retrieve data, using localhost just to try it out
public static MobileServiceClient DigestsTrackerClient = new MobileServiceClient("http://localhost:28451/");
```

Code on WeekItem.cs

```
// Method to get data from Mobile Services
public static async void GetWeekItems(List<WeekItem> passer)
{
    // Getting a InvalidOperationException down here
    IMobileServiceTable<WeekItem> weekTable = App.DigestsTrackerClient.GetTable<WeekItem>();
    passer = await weekTable.ToListAsync();    
}
```

More information on the exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: No 'id' member found on type 'TechDigest.Model.WeekItem'.
```

Also, here is the model for the object that I am trying to retrieve:

```
public class WeekItem
{
    public int WeekID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ImageURI { get; set; }
}
```

This error really confusing since I basically copied the code from [a demo made by an Azure engineer (18:50)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fYczGtSwhk) and mine throws this weird exception, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we recommend migrating to [Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-value-prop/), since Mobile Services is deprecated.

The error tells you the issue--you need an Id field on the client. Add a string property to your client data class (`WeekItem` in your case) called Id:

`public string Id { get; set; }`

You might also be interested in these step-by-step tutorials:

- [Create a Windows app with Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/)
- [Add authentication to your Windows app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-users/)
- [Enable offline sync for your Windows app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-offline-data/)

Comment: It is worth trying to solve it? Since you say it's fairly advanced? How do I add an Id field on the client? You mean add an "Id" string to my object (WeekItem)? Is this going to still happen if I switch to Azure Mobile Apps?

Comment: Yes - you literally add "public string Id { get; set; }" to your WeekItem class.  This will solve the issue.  Yes, it will still happen when you switch to Azure Mobile Apps.