# Seed table .NET backend Azure Mobile Apps error

Tags: .net, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I want to add a `DataObject` of my own to Azure Mobile Apps on top of the `TodoItem` that is supplied in the template. Here is what I have done:

1. Add new `DataObject`:

   ```
   public class Digests : EntityData
   {
       public string Title { get; set; }
       public string ImageURI { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Create new Controller called `DigestsController.cs`
3. Add `public DbSet<Digests> DigestItems { get; set; }` to my `AppContext.cs`. This is supposed to create the table that will hold `Digests` items.
4. Add `context.Set<Digests>().Add(new Digests { Id = "2016", Title = "Test", ImageURI = "someUriHere" });` to my `Startup.MobileApp.cs` on the `Seed` under the `AppInitializer` class. This is supposed to seed a row of data in my `Digests` table.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016543/extending-base-mobile-azure-sample-net-backend) and the way he solved it, this should work! But whenever I try to pull down data from my client app:

```
public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient("http://app.azurewebsites.net/");
IMobileServiceTable<Digests> Digests = App.MobileService.GetTable<Digests>();
Weeks = await Digests.ToListAsync();
```

Or pull down data with the template app that I can download from Azure Portal:

```
private MobileServiceCollection<TodoItem, TodoItem> items;
private IMobileServiceTable<TodoItem> todoTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<TodoItem>();
items = await todoTable.Where(todoItem => todoItem.Complete == false).ToCollectionAsync();
```

I get this:

[image]
Also, when I go into SQL Server Management Studio there's nothing! No `TodoItems` table (which should be there from the template code) and no `Digests` table.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:

1. Create DataModels
2. Create Controllers (Visual Studio automatically prompts the mobile app to create the tables).
3. Go into Startup.MobileApps.cs and seed if you want to (completely optional).

Answer (score 1):

The question that you referenced ([Extending base mobile azure sample (.net backend)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016543/extending-base-mobile-azure-sample-net-backend)) was for Azure Mobile Services. The same code might not work for Azure Mobile Apps, because there have been a lot of changes to the server SDK.

Instead, the easiest way to create a new table controller is to use the tooling in Visual Studio. Install the latest [Azure SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/).

Add your new data class, inheriting from `EntityData` as you have done. Build the project. Then, right-click your project, and select **Add -> New Scaffolded Item**. Select **Azure Mobile Apps Table Controller.** See screen shot below.

Note that publishing your project does not create the database table, since Entity Framework Code First creates the database once it is accessed for the first time. See [The server database is not created](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/wiki/Help,-my-app-isn't-working!#the-server-database-is-not-created-net-server-sdk-with-entity-framework) in the Mobile Apps Wiki.

[image]

Comment: I actually found out that the references changed between Mobile Services and Mobile Apps, so even my code was right I was getting errors for not having the right package installed. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: That's right, you need to match up the right client and server packages. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-client-and-server-versioning/

Answer (score 0):

> > public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient("http://app.azurewebsites.net/");

From the code you provided. Based on my understanding, you deployed your mobile application to Azure Web app. I think it is not a good choice. I would suggest you deploy your application to Mobile Service, then try the code below:

```
        public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(
            "https://<mobile service name>.azure-mobile.net/",
            "<mobile service key>"  //we could find this key in Azure portal Mobile service -> management key
        );
```

If your data model changes, please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-code-first-migrations/#seeding fore more dtails

Best Regards,

Jambor

Comment: [Another Msft referent recommended me to use Mobile Apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38154246/retrieving-data-from-azure-mobile-services) b/c Mobile services is phasing out. Is there no way to fix this issue with Mobile Apps? Why is it that I need to switch back?

Comment: I have also revisited the Azure link for seeding countless times. The answer I'm looking for is not there.

Comment: @ananhalz Yes, I'm from the Azure Mobile product team, and you should definitely switch to Mobile Apps. Mobile Services is deprecated and should not be used for new apps.

Comment: Don't worry! Once you advised me to switch I have been going on with Mobile Apps. It's a learning process but really great at the same time, thank you!